# Conflict between mhchem and pdftooltip (pdfcomment package)?

Tags: incompatibility, mhchem, pdfcomment

I tried to hide some text into a pdftooltip, which was working fine up to now (when I used TeXLive 2011).

I now upgraded to MacTeX 2014 and now I get an error, if there is a chemical formula in this hidden Text.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{color} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\newcommand{\weg}[1]{\pdftooltip{\textcolor{red}{\tiny\bfseries{}w}}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\ce{CO2}

the following text is hidden: \weg{hidden text \ce{CO2}}

\end{document}
```

I'm using MacTeX 2014 and I get the following error:

```
   ./MinimalExample.tex:19: Undefined control sequence. \mhchem@ce ...ate
   {s}\chardef \mhchem@ce@substate 
   =0\relax \mhchem@ce@result... l.19   ...text is hidden: \weg{hidden text
   \ce{CO2}}
```

How can I solve that?

---

EDIT: with TeXLive 2011, there was no error message, but the chemical formula was not correctly written in the pdftooltip, e. g. \ce{ZrO2} became *"3222378 * . Now with Josef's solution, at least the characters of the formula seem to be printed correctly in the tooltip.

Comment: This is Martin Hensel, the author of mhchem. Oh dear, that looks complicated. Unfortunately, I cannot offer a solution immediately. (I am about to rewrite some core parts completely, BTW.) I did not use pdfcomment before. It's kind of surprising that it worked before, because `\pdfcomment` cannot hande any math and `\ce` is using math mode internally. What was the output with your TeXLive 2011?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a good idea to contact Martin Hensel, the maintainer of `mhchem`! `pdfcomment` was not updated for quite a while. So, I guess the problem was introduced with an update of `mhchem`!

As a workaround for the moment, simply add `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\ce\relax}` to your preamble. That's not a solution but your document will compile at least.

[image]

Comment: thanks, good idea! The workaround lets the document compile and I've contacted Martin Hensel